# How to convert my iCloud Photo Library into H256/HEIC/HEVC

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, heic

I have iPhone 11 Pro and MacBook Pro 16", both are powerful enough to handle HEIC/HEVC. I just found that significant part of my iCloud Photo Library has an unoptimized MOV files recorded on previous iPhones:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to convert library to modern format keeping all the metadata?

Comment: Are you looking for iPhone-based solutions or does your library get synced to a computer as well?

Comment: @nohillside I am looking for ANY solution that would work :) I am syncing both Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

For **images**, you could use this iOS app to batch converting anything to **HEIF**:

I personally use this app for my own Photo Library!

**Half - Cut Media Storage in ½**
https://apps.apple.com/app/half-cut-media-storage-in/id1288721004

For **videos**, I haven't test anything solid yet. However, I found a blog post https://rienkjanschurer.nl/how-to-make-your-apple-photos-library-smaller-use-h265-hevc-for-your-videos/

and it uses Permute, which looks promising!
https://software.charliemonroe.net/permute/